# How do I make a warn command using discord.py?

Tags: python, warnings, discord, discord.py

I've tried several ways like to send a direct message to send a warning, but I couldn't find a correct script and I've tried using the documentation and I couldn't find any useful information and I was wondering if I could have some help..

Comment: Programming is an actual skill. You'll have to learn it should you want to write your own code.

Answer (score 2):

Passing [`Client.send_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.send_message) a `User` object will allow you to send a message to that user. (On the experimental rewrite branch, this has been replaced by [`User.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.User.send)) Below is a basic example

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    author = message.author
    if author == client.user:
        return
    if 'password' in message.content:
        await client.send_message(author, 'Do not say password')
```